# Click Event in Jqgrid Row number

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I have jqgrid with sortable rows, it is working fine in web browsers. But, Having trouble when testing the grid in Tablets and Mobile devices.

The selected row is not highlighted in devices. that's why am not able to perform the edit and delete operations.

Do we have an option to write code in grid rownumber click? if Yes,that will be more helpful.

So, please suggest me on this issue.

This is My Jqgrid :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var pageWidth = $(window).width();
        var lastSel;
        $("#sortrows").setGridWidth(pageWidth, true);
        $('#sortrows').jqGrid('GridUnload');
        jQuery("#sortrows").jqGrid({
            datatype: "local",
            mtype: "get",
            //data : myData,
            hoverrows: false,
            jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, id: "Index" },
            ajaxGridOptions: { timeout: 30000 },
            colNames: PricelistHeaderColName,
            colModel: PricelistHeaderModel,
            id: 'Index',
            localReader: { id: 'Index' },
            prmNames: { id: "Index" },
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            hidegrid: false,
            rownumbers: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            height: 'auto',
            width: pageWidth,
            scrollOffset: 0,
            gridview: true,
            autowidth: true,
            shrinkToFit: true,
            pager: '#psortrows',
            firstsortorder: 'asc',
            sortname: 'Sort',
            autoencode: true,
            loadonce: true,
            ignoreCase: true,
            multiselect: false,
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "asc",
            sortable: true,
            caption: "PriceList Headers",
            editurl: "../Header/Save",                        
        });
```

Comment: Is the same code working in desktop view?

Comment: Yes it is working in desktop view and I can do edit,delete operations